# redirect with special POST headers

Tags: php, redirect, https, http-headers

In my system, a user will enter data into a form, and it will be processed by a PHP script.

This php script will manipulate this data around, and then needs to redirect the user to an https page, but also send along its own POST parameters.

So, for example, if

```
send-me.php?name=chuck+norris
```

is called, the user should be redirected to

```
https://secret.hideout.com/
```

where a POST parameters are

```
is_chuck="1"
be_polite="definitely"
run_away="what's the point?"
```

Is this possible? How?

Thanks

Comment: Do you control `secret.hideout.com` or is it a 3rd party site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't control the target site, the only way I can see to do this is having a second `<form>` on the PHP page with the `https://` URL as the target, and the values as hidden fields.

However, this way, the values remain manipulable by the user after your PHP script has changed them.

Alternatively, depending on the nature of what you need to do, consider manipulating the values on client side using JavaScript before the form gets posted.

Comment: This is the only way I could think of too, but I hate how kludgy it feels :\

Answer (score 2):

You cannot redirect to a URL with POST parameters.

You can redirect to a URL with GET parameters (appended to the end of the URL):

```
https://secret.hideout.com/?is_chuck=1&be_polite=definitely&run_away=now
```

You can use CURL to call a URL with POST parameters, but you can't redirect to it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach is to create a form and call the submit from javascript.

in the send-me.php after you parse the data you need, you display this html:

```
<form name="send" action="https://secret.hideout.com/" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="is_chuck" value="1" />
...
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.forms.send.submit();
</script>
```

however this has cons:

- the https://secret.hideout.com/ will know by the Referer header that you sent the client and from, to his page.
- the client can tamper the post data to know what has being posted.

in the other way you can make the post server side, but the client will not have a proper navegation because cookies and etc.

Comment: yeah. I think this is the only solution. kludgy, but hey... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> needs to redirect the user to an https page, but also send along its own POST parameters.

That's just impossible. POST is a *request* header, not response.

So, do not interfere between a user and whatever service.
There are ALWAYS a legal way to get transaction result. Use it.

Comment: I don't control the https page nor the method I need to use to access it. GET is not supported.

Comment: So, just do not interfere and let user to go to the service directly

Comment: You won't just give me the benefit of the doubt and assume that would be impractical? 
I have 20 such POST params that need to be sent, some of which need to be collected from a database and it is imperative that these are not mucked up by the user